# TypeError: fun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'link'

Tags: python

I am facing a basic problem and unable to resolve it. I am getting this error

> TypeError: fun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'link'

If i give `self` as positional argument in call of `fun()` as `fun(self,glit)` then I an getting

> Undefined Variable self

There is no indentation problem in this small function. I also tried `self.fun(glit)` But it is also giving

> Undefined Variable self.

If I delete the word `self` from `def fun(self,link):` then it is also not working. 
Any way out?

```
class myClass:

    def fun(self,link):
        print("fun")

    glit = "http://www.google.com"
    fun(glit)
```

Comment: self.fun(glit) should work, if it's outside of the class, you need an instance of thet class and call instance.fun(glit)

Comment: @iScrE4m I already tried it it is giving `Undefined variable self`

Comment: Is this your full code?

Comment: @iScrE4m Yes it is whole code. Basic purpose of this is to eliminate the error.

Comment: @tynn I want to use the class. Basic purpose of this is to eliminate the error.

Comment: @tynn classess are mandatory. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to call that code from the class. Class should only contain methods, not your logic. You should call it from outside of the class:

```
class = myClass()
glit = "http://www.google.com/"
class.fun(glit)
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be naming your variables keywords

Answer (score 0):

[Edit]
Use the `__init__` function to set variables inside of a class, like

```
def __init__(self): 
    self.glit = 'www.google.com'
```

Now use `self.fun(self.glit)`